# How to config mosquitto.conf in Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm a newbie and I have used Mosquitto ( http://mosquitto.org ). I have installed it with mosquitto-1.0.5-install-cygwin.exe, and am running it as windows service. But I can't see any log. This is my mosquitto.conf:

```
log_dest topic

log_dest syslog

log_type error

log_type warning

log_type notice

log_type information
```

Please help me!

Comment: It is not obvious to me what exactly it is you want to achieve. Do you want to configure it to specify and use a log file?

Comment: yes, I can work with mosquitto (pub, sub) but i can't see log in Windows. I changed mosquitto.conf same above and hope it work, I think that place to log in /var/log/messages but i ca'nt find out folder in Windows.

Comment: `# Note that if the broker is running as a Windows service it will default to
# "log_dest none" and neither stdout nor stderr logging is available.`
i'm not sure whether it affects writing to log file

Answer (score 2):

```
log_dest syslog
```

This option will send log messages to the Windows application log that you can find in Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Computer Management->Event Viewer.

Alternatively if you start the broker manually rather than as a service you could use

```
log_dest stdout
```

or

```
log_dest stderr
```

and redirect the output to a file. It isn't currently possible to configure a file output explicitly.

Comment: I can see a log with `log_dest syslog`, but I get error: "Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.. No such file or directory.." in Event Viewer

Comment: You need to set persistence_location to a valid path or leave it unset to use the current directory. It is totally unrelated to logging though.